# Non-uniform pseudo-random variate generation techniques?

Tags: distributions, sampling, predictive-models, modeling, dataset

Suppose you have been presented with three of five data points in some sample. Of those provided are the minimum, median, and maximum. The mean and standard deviation have also been given.

How would you create an expression for the location of those two unique data points?

(Note: I am an undergraduate student with a limited understanding of advanced statistics.)

Comment: This is not random variate generation. It is solving for two missing data points in a sample of 5 given that you know three particular data points (minimum, mediian and maximum 0and the sample mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aaron,
This is not really a problem of statistics.  It is a problem of multiple equations with unknowns.
Given a set of Min, x, Median, y, Max.

Average is the sum of all of the terms divided by the number of terms:

Average = (Min + x + Median + y + Max)/5

Standard Deviation = sqrt of (((Min - Average)^2 + (x- Average)^2 + (Median - Average)^2 + (y - Average)^2 + (Max - Average)^2))/5)

Two equations and two unknowns solve for x and y.

Comment: This shows how you would solve for the two missing data points.  But a complicating factor is that one of the points say x must fall between the minimum and the median and the other say y between the median and the maximum.  This constraint may not be satisfied for arbitrary possible choices for the mean and variance.